# Internal error during IncrCalcPtrs - does not recur when I run the code the 2nd time

Tags: c++

The project holding the code has all default MSVS2008 settings.

Consider the following code using which I am familiarizing myself with various offerings of STL:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>

using namespace std;


template <class T> void print(const vector<T>& l)
{  // A generic print function for vectors
    cout << endl << "PV Size of vector is " << l.size() << "\n[";
    for(int i = 0; i < l.size(); i++)
    {
        cout<<l[i]<<",";
    }
    cout << "]\n";
}


int main()
{
    vector<double> vec1(4, 2.0);
    vector<double> vec2(4, 4.0);
    double init = 0.0;
    double summation = accumulate(vec1.begin(), vec1.end(), init);
    cout<<"Summation = "<<summation<<", init is "<<init<<endl;

    double ip = inner_product(vec1.begin(), vec1.end(), vec2.begin(), init);
    cout<<"ip = "<<ip<<", init is "<<init<<endl;

    int size = 6;
    int seed_value = 2;
    vector<int> vec3(size, seed_value);
    vector<int> result(size);
    partial_sum(vec3.begin(), vec3.end(), result.begin());
    cout<<"The partial sum of vec3 is ";
    print(vec3);

    int sz = 10;
    int value = 2;
    vector<int> vec4(sz);
    for(int it = 0; it < vec4.size(); it++){
        vec4[it] = value;
        value++;
    }
    vector<int> result2(vec4.size());
    adjacent_difference(vec4.begin(), vec4.end(), result2.begin());
    cout<<"Adjacent differenec of vec4 is ";
    print(vec4);

    return(0);
}
```

The first time I try to run this (under Windows 7, Visual Studio 2008) I get the following error:

```
c:\programming\numeric_algorithms_on_vectors.cpp(86) : warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch

c:\programming\numeric_algorithms_on_vectors.cpp(37) : warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch

c:\programming\numeric_algorithms_on_vectors.cpp(81) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void print(const std::vector<_Ty> &)' being compiled

        with
        [
            _Ty=int
        ]

Linking...

numeric_algorithms_on_vectors.obj : fatal error LNK1000: Internal error during     IncrCalcPtrs
  Version 9.00.30729.01
  ExceptionCode            = C0000005
  ExceptionFlags           = 00000000
  ExceptionAddress         = 00E6B8C0 (00E10000) "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft     Visual Studio 9.0\VC\bin\link.exe"
  NumberParameters         = 00000002
  ExceptionInformation[ 0] = 00000000
  ExceptionInformation[ 1] = 0000001C
CONTEXT:
  Eax    = 00000000  Esp    = 0042EAE8
  Ebx    = 3FFF0000  Ebp    = 0042EB04
  Ecx    = 77CB36FA  Esi    = 4000AF9C
  Edx    = 4000F774  Edi    = 00000000
  Eip    = 00E6B8C0  EFlags = 00010293
  SegCs  = 00000023  SegDs  = 0000002B
  SegSs  = 0000002B  SegEs  = 0000002B
  SegFs  = 00000053  SegGs  = 0000002B
  Dr0    = 00000000  Dr3    = 00000000
  Dr1    = 00000000  Dr6    = 00000000
  Dr2    = 00000000  Dr7    = 00000000
```

Yet, after clicking through the windows that tell me that my code did not compile/work properly, when I debug the same code again without making any changes to the code whatsoever, the program works. Is there a reason why the code would not compile/link/run the first time, yet run perfectly fine the next time?

Comment: "when I debug the same code again without making any changes to the code whatsoever" - are you **really, really** sure about that? What about configuration settings (like warning levels, code generation settings, compiler/linker switches, etc.)?

Comment: @In Silico: Yes...no change WHATSOEVER in the code/config settings occurs between the first and second run.

Comment: Can you reproduce this behavior?

Comment: The code works for me on VS2010. The warnings you are seeing are relatively meaningless and resolved easily by using an unsigned loop counter. The error you are seeing is an internal compiler error - none of us can debug that.

Comment: @In Silico: On closing the solution file and reopening it, the code compiles/links/runs fine the first time itself...I am still left with the 3 warnings though. I am unable to reproduce the "Internal error during IncrCalcPtrs" error...So...I guess as DeadMG says...I can live with this. Thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known problem in the linker for VS2008 SP1.  Fixed in VS2010, the feedback report [is here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/428381/fatal-error-lnk1000-internal-error-during-incrcalcptrs?wa=wsignin1.0).

I've seen this myself a few times, it only happens when it actually links incrementally.  For me it always resolved itself by forcing a full build through Build + Rebuild so that the .ilk file is deleted and re-created.  If that still doesn't work for you then you can turn the feature off with Project + Properties, Linker, General, Enable Incremental Linking.

Comment: Oh...thanks. Reassuring to know I am not bumping against a self-generated error/mistake. +1.